# Storing file names as variables in c++

Tags: c++

In the code below I have an array of structures.
Now I  want to store a text file of the same name that is entered by the user to `hello[1].fname`. How can I change my code for that?

```
struct customer{
    string fname;
    string lname;
    int age;        
} ;

int main()
{
    int x;
    ofstream client;

    cout<<"number ff family members?";

    cin>>x;
    customer hello[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {

      cin>>hello[i].fname;
      cin>>hello[i].lname;
      cin>>hello[i].age;

    }
    **client.open(hello[1].fname.text);**

    if(!client)
    {
        cout<<"error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: You have an error here: `customer hello[x];` remember in `c++` arrays must have a compile time constant size.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't allow whats know as Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) in C, so your code

```
cin>>x;
customer hello[x];
```

is not legal C++. Use a `std::vector<customer>` instead.

`x` and `i` should be of type `std::size_t` instead of `int` because `int` may not be big enough to accomodate for all possible object sizes/indexes.

Declare and define your variables where they're actually used. Instead

```
ofstream client;
// numerous lines of code
client.open( /*... */ );
```

do

```
// numerous lines of code
ofstream client( /* ... */ ); // use the constructor instead of open()
```

Last but not least:

```
client.open(hello[1].fname.text);
```

`customer::fname` is of type `std::string` which does not have a member called `text`. Simply use

```
ofstream client(hello[1].fname);
```

or

```
ofstream client(hello[1].fname.c_str());
```

if you have to work with a standard library implementation that doesn't support a constructor for `std::ofstream` that takes `std::string`s but only `const char *`.

PS: You are aware that arrays in C and C++ begin at index 0? Just curious cause you use `hello[1].fname` as your file name.